# Create a subquery to filter on windowed function value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm trying to add ROW_NUMBER functionality to EF Core and filter by it.

After adding custom function, it works fine in `Select` but doesn't work in `Where`, because of malformed SQL.

Linq:

```
var query = dbContext.OrderItems
    .Select(i => new
    {  
        i.Name,
        RowNumber = EF.Functions.RowNumber(i.ProductId)
    })
    .Where(i => i.RowNumber == 1);
```

Translates into:

```
SELECT
   i.NAME,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.ProductId) AS RowNumber
FROM
   OrderItems AS i
WHERE
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.ProductId) = CAST(1 AS bigint)
```

Error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.
```

To correct this SQL, I need to create a subquery:

```
SELECT
  t.NAME,
  t.RowNumber
FROM (
   SELECT
      i.NAME,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.ProductId) AS RowNumber
   FROM
      OrderItems AS i
) t
WHERE
  t.RowNumber = CAST(1 AS bigint)
```

I've found an article on how to do this in EF Core 2.

> Probably, the easiest way is to introduce a method that gives EF a hint that the previous query should be a sub query. Fortunately, we don't have do much because internally the method AsQueryable (or rather the expression associated with it) does just that.

https://www.thinktecture.com/en/entity-framework-core/making-rownumber-more-useful-in-2-1/

But this approach does nothing in EF Core 3.1

Is there a way to create a subquery?

Comment: How did you restructure everything else from thinktecture to get this to work in 3.1? I tried a few ways but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Miles, maybe this code can help you: https://gist.github.com/xiety/55451024aac0af999eac137db2e8e8e6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the EF Core 3.1 source code, the only way I see to force subquery before applying `where` filter is to introduce a query limit (i.e. `Skip` and/or `Take`).

From the two possible fake limit operators (`Skip(0)` and `Take(int.MaxValue)`),  looks like choosing the later is better, because the former also requires some ordering (even fake).

So the workaround is to insert

```
.Take(int.MaxValue)
```

before `.Where(...)`.

The generated SQL is not perfect (has fake `TOP` clause), but at least is valid.

Comment: Has it changed for EfCore5? I now tried `Take(int.MaxValue)` on it and it does work anyway... So thank you!

Comment: Wondering if there are any other solutions to this issue with EF Core 3.1. The Skip/Take work-around doesn't work for me because they cause EF Core to fail rendering: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '...' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Comment: @JohnFullman Nope, as I wrote, this is the only way I found for EFC 3.1. Are you sure the reason for failed translation is not something else in your query?

Comment: @IvanStoev I think you are correct. I took out my reference to RowNumber() and it still threw an error (although now it's an InvalidCastException). It seems to be that when EF 3.1 tries to project to the sub query it fails (most likely due to an underlying GroupBy). Thanks for the nudge.